# (Play Framework) Suitable IDE to edit Twirl templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, twirl

I'm editing some fairly long Twirl template html files in Intellij IDEA, but it's basically like a text editor without function/variable prompt or even the correct keyword highlighting.

Curious to know if there's a plugin/editor that will make my life a lot easier?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the Scala plugin?

Comment: @marcospereira Yes scala plugin working, but it doesn't seem to apply to the .scala.html file with Twirl template engine.

Comment: @Andy Are you using IDEA Ultimate or Community?

Comment: @danielnixon Community. Is it included in the paying Ultimate version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look the [Intellij matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) it says that scala plugin is available on community version but the play plugin is only available on the ultimate version.

1 - If you are still a student with a university issued email you can apply for a 1 year of ultimate [license](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/) of intellij.

2- Change your IDE to eclipse.

3 - Buy a license.

Comment: Sadly, using scala 2.13 eliminates Scala IDE (unfortunately)